# How to send Personalized Attachments via Sendgrid Dynamic Template?

Tags: python, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I need to send diffrent attachments to diffrent email ids , the emails will have dynamic content so i am using Dynamic template.

Personlizations request does not attachments.

Does anyone know how to send Personalized Attachments via Sendgrid Dynamic Template?

Tried using Python Sendgrid API Post request to send emails using dynamic template id. I can send emails. I cannot find a way to dynamically add attachments.